# DNS record to port

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, srv

I have my brand new website hosted on amazon ec2:

- IP: http://52.215.150.134:8020/
- AWS Domain: ec2-52-215-150-134.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8020

As you can see, it is exposed on port 8020 because 80 is already in use by another web service.

I'd like my domain (hosted on godaddy) to point to that website. I know it is not possible to point to port 8020 with a A or CNAME record. It's not clear if it's possible with SRV or other ways. I tried this, but it does not work:

[image: SRV redirection]

Any help ?

Comment: It is technically possible to do this with `SRV` records because they were designed exactly for this... but for that to work the application needs to use them. And web browsers do not take them into account, and this will not change soon and maybe never. Hence you will need a web proxying setup somewhere to translate the port, besides the DNS resolution to find the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an Application Load Balancer in front of  your instance which can forward traffic to 8020 and have CNAME mapping to ALB url.

Comment: Do you know a good resource that explains this? I am using docker and could add e.g., an nginx instance. What's not clear to me is how the load balancer can retrieve the original url to perform the redirect to the right port.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-application-load-balancer.html    You may accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: It wasn't as straightforward as I hoped, but I got it to work. In amazon, the redirect can be done on the host header (i.e., the original url).

Comment: Did ALB hell you out?